# propensity score matching for categorical

Tags: statistics, matching, categorical-data

Can I do propensity score matching if my data are categorical? Let say my independent variable are: education (primary, secondary, college), has children (yes,no), wealth index (rich, middle, poor), accessibility (difficult, easy). Or can I make it dummy? But if yes, I think it's difficult to match the cases. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Propensity score matching doesn't depend on the variable type of the covariates. You can estimate a logistic regression model for the propensity score and then match on the predicted values for each unit. The whole point of propensity score matching is to reduce your covariate set to a single numerical summary: the propensity score. So it's not hard for a simple matching algorithm to match on the propensity score. Check out the `MatchIt` package in R if you want to perform propensity score matching. Note that like all statistical methods, not knowing what you're doing can make your results invalid, so try to consult with an expert as your proceed.